# Shorten DDNS name in /etc/hosts or similar

Tags: linux, networking, dns, hosts, ddns

I have Dyanamic IP, therefore I'm using No-IP with a DDNS name. However it is quite long.

The hosts file `/etc/hosts` uses the format:

```
{ip.add.re.ss}     {host-name.here}
```

but, and I have a DDNS name which I want to "shorten".

So My DDNS name is e.g. `xyzabc123tuvasdqwe.noip.me`

This DDNS name points to a dynamic IP hosted at my home with an IP e.g. `x.y.z.a`

but this DDNS name I want to shorten to say  e.g. `xyz`

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what you are really asking. If you make a change to the hosts file, it will only be for that specific machine. If you want to shorten it, why not use something like https://goo.gl/ https://bitly.com/ or any of these http://bit.do/list-of-url-shorteners.php ? That is their purpose...

Comment: @acejavelin in your hosts file, you say `127.0.0.1     ls`. Thne `ping ls` refers to 127.0.0.1 or say `ssh root@ls` which ssh's into localhost. Now in my case, I do not want to type out `root@abcxyz123ertuiomnoqwe.noip.com` because who wants to do that. I want to shorten that to `ssh root@abc`. does this make sense?

Comment: If you want to shorten typing in a shell, simply add an entry to your start-up file (such as `.bashrc`), eg: `export dip=abcxyz123ertuiomnoqwe.noip.com`. Then your command becomes `ssh root@$dip`.

Comment: @Cybex Got it, the problem is your IP is dynamic and it can (potentially) change, making your host entry invalid, that's why I recommended a URL shortener, it can change `reallylonghostname.ddnsservice.com` to `goog.gl/abc123`. Another thought is  using aliases for common commands.

Comment: @AFH I was hoping there was another method do get this done instead of using aliases. Since that brings in inconsistency in the system. but thanks anyway

Comment: @Cybex - I was proposing a shell variable, not an alias. Where is the inconsistency? It will work on all shells and it can be added to all users. This seems to be less inconsistent than modifying `hosts` (which won't work). Another option might be to use a key macro, but I don't see this as less inconsistent.